# Complete form with cURL using PHP (POST)

Tags: php, ajax, post, curl, httprequest

I'm trying to make a registration system where users that visit us and register to our website will have an account on a secondary website in order for them to be able to see some opportunities.

So here it goes: [The website were I want to POST the Form and Register](https://opportunities.aiesec.org/programmes)

My code so far

```
    <?php
    // set post fields
    $post = [
    // this i don't master fell free to approach the subject for future reffrance
    'authenticity_token'=>'vhmPffEAIiIbjo36K8CI77+YDQfMPBWEG8ymplsGJ0w=',
    'user[email]'=>'test@gmail.com',
    'user[first_name]'=>'test',
    'user[last_name]'=>'test',
    'user[password]'=>'12345678',//smart password (had to be 8char long)
    'user[country]'=>'Country(placeholder)',
    'user[mc]'=>'1560', //id of the country
    'user[lc_input]'=>'1475', //id of the dropdown
    'user[lc]'=>'1475',//id of the dropdown
    'commit'=>'REGISTER',//value of submit

    ];

    $ch = curl_init('https://auth.aiesec.org/users/sign_in');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);

    // execute!
    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    // close the connection, release resources used
    curl_close($ch);

    // do anything you want with your response
    var_dump($response);
    ?>
```

Story:

As a user I want to be able to complete a form on domain A and at the same time have an account on domain B using CURL or even JS and AJAX.

If you have any solution to achieve this please let me know :) You can also have a look on the website.

Thank you!

**Late edit**

[image: Postman POST account]

I`ve made this in POSTMAN. So I think I should be able to make the for post that information. If you have other suggestions.

**In this case server returns 500 as success and 200 as error (security)**

**Final Working Code**

```
    <?php

    // set post fields
    $post = [
    // this i don`t master fell free to approach the subject for future reffrance
    'authenticity_token'=>'NKWAg8mGA9gUueBaJ5Og+oEOC5O2rZarZzMK+GnjuCA=',
    'user[email]'=>'',
    'user[first_name]'=>'',
    'user[last_name]'=>'',
    'user[password]'=>'',//smart password (had to be 8char long)
    'user[country]'=>'',
    'user[mc]'=>'', //id of the country
    'user[lc_input]'=>'', //id of the dropdown
    'user[lc]'=>'',//id of the dropdown
    'commit'=>'REGISTER',//value of submit

    ];

    $ch = curl_init('https://auth.aiesec.org/users/');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);


    // execute!
    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    // close the connection, release resources used
    curl_close($ch);

    // do anything you want with your response
    var_dump($response);


    ?>
```

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: I just need to be able to created an account on another website when the user completes a form on mine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are connection via *https*. So you should add these lines:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
```

I tested your code and the website responded "Wrong username / password". That means curl is connecting correctly.

Comment: Yup. You are right. A problem that I have identified is the way I`m going to get to the registration form cuz if you check the provided link  https://opportunities.aiesec.org/programmes . This means that i have to click on the Login / Signup button

Comment: By the way, I think the forms POSTS to *https://auth.aiesec.org/users* for registration, not *https://auth.aiesec.org/users/sign_in*

Comment: So I should change the link to this /users. But the message on that link is this --The page you were looking for doesn't exist.

You may have mistyped the address or the page may have moved.--

Comment: Will cURL  look for a form and complete it or will it make a POST method like this auth.aiesec.org/users?username=2323&email=test@g.com ??

Comment: You should analyze the process very carefully. For example, use the *Network-Tab* in *Firebug* (if you are using Firefox) to see what is hapenning when you click the register button.

Comment: Check my postman update picture. It seems that if I post that it will create the account

Comment: Curl will not complete any from. And POST-Parameters are not written in the URL. You should first analyze the data that is sent when you create an account on the website (for example with *Firebug*). Then copy that data and try it with curl. If you connect correctly (SSL) and send the exact same data it should work (you should maybe change the username so you dont try registering the same username twice).